# Aligning a text paragraph (link string) under a table

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table, paragraph

I've got a table and a line of links attached to images. I can't get these links under the table. Whatever I do, it just stays above it.

My code can seem bulky or just wrong.

```
<table style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:165px" border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="5">
<tbody><tr>
<tr style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#ffffff;">
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2NaNp7nmYMg?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_z5rqY8tAYQ?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dheMabIam7c?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
</tr>

<p style="padding-left: 750px; padding-top: 50px"
<a href="https://twitter.com/ShadowKiller158" target="_blank"></a>
<a href="https://youtube.com/user/shadowman158" target="_blank"><img src="youtube.png" alt="YouTube" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/ShadowKiller158" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alexander.schewior" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/ShadowManTM/" target="_blank"><img src="steam.png" alt="Steam" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/shadowmantm/" target="_blank"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: You haven't closed your tbody and table tags or your opening p tag.  Also is this all your code and styles - if so then there is no reason for the p to appear above the table

Comment: Silly me! Thank you, would have never noticed that on my own. It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed your table or tbody tag. You have also not closed your opening P tag.

So you code should be:

```
<table style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:165px" border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="5">
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#ffffff;">
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2NaNp7nmYMg?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_z5rqY8tAYQ?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dheMabIam7c?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p style="padding-left: 750px; padding-top: 50px">
<a href="https://twitter.com/ShadowKiller158" target="_blank"></a>
<a href="https://youtube.com/user/shadowman158" target="_blank"><img src="youtube.png" alt="YouTube" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/ShadowKiller158" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alexander.schewior" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/ShadowManTM/" target="_blank"><img src="steam.png" alt="Steam" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/shadowmantm/" target="_blank"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
</p>
```

Here is a useful tutorial on opening and closing HTML tags:
http://www.easyhtmlcode.com/lesson1.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just forgot to close the tbody and table tags. Thanks to Pete for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful about opening and closing of HTML tags as some browsers will automatically handle unclosed tags and wont let you know there is a mismatch.

Every paired tag should be closed at the right place ! Otherwise it will get you in trouble !

```
<table style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:165px" border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="5">
<tbody><tr>
<tr style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#ffffff;">
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2NaNp7nmYMg?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_z5rqY8tAYQ?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
<td><div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dheMabIam7c?ecver=2" width="481" height="274" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p style="padding-left: 750px; padding-top: 50px">
<a href="https://twitter.com/ShadowKiller158" target="_blank"></a>
<a href="https://youtube.com/user/shadowman158" target="_blank"><img src="youtube.png" alt="YouTube" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/ShadowKiller158" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alexander.schewior" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/ShadowManTM/" target="_blank"><img src="steam.png" alt="Steam" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/shadowmantm/" target="_blank"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="75" border="0" height="75"></a>
</p>
```

Good Luck and enjoy learning HTML